# SQL : How can I get previous day

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff, dateadd

How can I get the result in the `PreviousDay` column that the day should be -1 from the day in `efdt` column for all rows?
If the `efdt` date is **2001-04-02** the result in PreviousDay should be **2001-04-01** and DATEDIFF is `334`
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izA39.png) attached with it please refer it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SQL Server [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window function over the "*efdt*" field, which will take the following value given two clauses:

- `PARTITION BY`, which indicates the groups to work on
- `ORDER BY`, which decided which value to take according to an order imposed by one (or more) of your fields.

```
SELECT T.*,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, efdt, PreviousDay)
FROM (SELECT T1.*,
             LEAD(efdt) OVER(PARTITION BY emcd ORDER BY efdt) AS PreviousDay
      FROM psf206 T1) AS T
ORDER BY emcd, efdt
```

Check the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90ed7225e9ab5914625296f0d4827ef1) here.

**Note**: if you want one day less for each row, just add `-1` after the `DATEDIFF` operation ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5c2d149c748c218bec6eb5c9994cf06d)).